# How to check whether a MySql connection is alive in C API?

Tags: c++, mysql, c

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-connecting.html), I know how to check MySql connection state in C++

> These methods can be used to check the connection state or reconnect:
>
> - sql::Connection::isValid() checks whether the connection is alive.
> - sql::Connection::reconnect() reconnects if the connection has gone down.

**Is there a C API to do the same thing?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the link you shared is to Connector/C++, which is a C++ API. What you're looking for is [Connector/C](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-c/en/), or just the [regular C API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api.html).

[`mysql_stat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-stat.html) is a function which will return status of the server to tell you if the connection is gone.